# Is hunger pushing cognitive ability in humans?

Tags: endocrinology, intelligence, cognition

We have a lot of those questions here that base on personal anecdotes and I try to avoid asking any of those. Still, after skipping breakfast and an extremely effective work day so far I started wondering.
I have always felt, that for most cognitive tasks I perform best before breakfast. Of course some of it is sure related to being very awake and supposedly having a biorhythm that favours working in the morning, but I have always related this to not having eaten and also surprisingly not feeling hungry at all until basically deciding to eat "because I really should eat something" around noon.
So today I decided to find out, if this phenomenon is more widely known or just anecdotal for me. Of course there is a lot of information on how digestion makes you feel tired and you should not expect to be very productive directly after eating. That was not what I am looking for.

Finally I found this 2006 NY Times article about "[Empty-Stomach Intelligence](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/12/10/magazine/10section1C.t-1.html?_r=0)", where it is stated that at least for mice being "mildly starving" seems to increase cognitive ability based on the hormone ghrelin targeting not only the hippothalamus, but also the hippocampus. 
I then tried finding a relevant publication and was only lead to [this one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1618869/), describing the original study about ghrelin influencing food intake, but seemingly not the "sidetrack" of it influencing cognitive abilities during starving.

Now I am lost. Is there any newer publication about this phenomenon that I completely missed, possibly even in relation to how humans can perform cognitive tasks while being mildly starved?

Comment: my guess is following: today people have much more food and food has much more nutritious value than in previous times. So average body is generally running in parasympathetic mode, digesting and resting. That takes attention from CNS, including brain functioning. Mild fasting releases that external pressure. I'd suggest search for link between daily glucose level and brain ability/performance

Comment: Still it is curious for me because it is so counterintuitive. Most people I know if they have to work hard on a cognitive level they tend to snack nuts, chocolate, anything they are used to to keep their attention up. And this does boost your attention for a short while. The mild fasting on the other hand seems to be a more long-term approach (long-term being around 6 hours).

Comment: This question is more suitable for cognitive sciences and I vote to close therefore. I bet it will be well received there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a well targeted question for Cognitive Sciences. +1 for the nice question :)

Comment: I think it has a biological answer. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that either leptin or ghrelin (or both) have an effect on cognitive performance. Orexins also regulate wakefulness, so they may be part of it as well, as more wakefulness tends to produce better attention, and lots of cognitive ability depends on focused attention.

Comment: @rumtscho I was kind of looking for that biological answer, especially any additional explanation to the ghrelin theory from the newspaper article. I am not at all into cognitive science, so saw this as a biological (endocrinology) question.

Comment: @skymningen Moderate hunger can serve as an activating factor for the body to increase its alertness and thus, as a side effect, can mildly push cognitive ability. Another factor which can make you percieve hunger as a more sober state of mind is that endorphines are released in response to satisfaction of hunger. Endorphines are known to be able to cause unconditioned happiness which reduces the need in any activity, even make one sleepy, thus seemingly decreasing cognitive abilities of the person.